# How do I configure handler using serverless typescript without unrecognized property 'http'?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

The serverless error message is

```
at 'functions.parse.events[0]': unrecognized property 'http'
```

The template is https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-typescript

The handler typescript file

```
    import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handlerResolver';

    export default {
    handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
    events: [
      {
        http: {
          method: 'get',
          path: 'parse'
       },
       s3: "${s3:}"
     }
   ],
    environment: {
     CONFIG_TABLE : process.env.CONFIG_TABLE,
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the ${s3:} mis-configuration.

Misconfiguration in further events will cause the http event to register as an unrecognised property.